# How to build a Docker image for client service of Spring Cloud Config Server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-cloud-config

I have built a Docker image for cloud config service. I have another service `employee` for which I want to build a Docker image. This client service will read data source configuration properties from the config server

I am able to connect the `employee` service successfully with config service on localhost without Docker. The problem is only that I am not able to build a Docker image for the `employee` service.

On running `mvn package dockerfile:build` command for the employee service I get the following error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Below is the `bootstrap.yml` file located at `src/main/resources` directory

```
spring:
  application:
    name: employee
  profiles:
    active: dev
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://configserver:8071
```

Config service's bootstrap.yml file

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  profiles:
    active: native,dev
    
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        #Local configuration: This locations can either of classpath or locations in the filesystem.
        native:
          #Reads from a specific filesystem folder 
          search-locations: classpath:/config
    
server:
  port: 8071
```

employee.properties file in config directory

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

employee-dev.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/employee?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

This is probably because the container of config server with hostname `configserver` is not up. I am not sure what hostname I should provide. Even if I want to build the image of `employee` service by starting the container of config server, it won't be on `configserver` host but on `localhost`. This is probably why the build is failing?

I want to build the Docker image of employee service so that its container can be fired up using the `docker-compose up` command

**Edit:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53353138/10195722) question is similar but I already have the `spring-cloud-starter-config` dependency added in my client service and it still gives me the same error on build

**Edit 2**

You don't have to separately build a Docker image for the client service at all!

When I ran `docker-compose up` command I noticed the following line in output

```
c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://configserver:8071
```

But I was still not sure if it was actually reading the data from the config server. So I purposely added incorrect database credentials in config server properties file for my service and the service startup failed! Now I am sure that my `employee` service is reading the data from the config server

I am still not sure how can I achieve creating a new Docker image for my `employee` service.

Answer (score 1):

Did  you try changing the URL param db to actual host of vhostname ?

db =change it to IP addess or accessable load balancer URL

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/employee?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false

Comment: That didn't help. The main problem is I am providing configserver as cloud.config.uri but as cloud config docker container is not running, so it cannot find the configserver service and throws the error.